# How can we display the name of each command whose manual page mentions a specific person

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can we display the name of each command whose manual page mentions a specific person in Linux? eg. Kernighan.

Is it possible to display the author name of the manual command, Please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man man`:

```
-K, --global-apropos
              Search for text in all manual  pages.   This  is  a  brute-force
              search,  and is likely to take some time; if you can, you should
              specify a section to reduce the number of pages that need to  be
              searched.   Search terms may be simple strings (the default), or
              regular expressions if the --regex option is used.
```

So just do:

```
$ man -wK Kernighan
/usr/share/man/man1/pic.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/chem.1.gz 
/usr/share/man/man1/gawk.1.gz 
/usr/share/man/man1/ex.1.gz 
/usr/share/man/man1/ex.1.gz 
/usr/share/man/man1/makeindex.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/Pod::Man.3perl.gz
....
```

I have spent some time to filter out the authors, and I only came with the following:

```
 what=Kernighan; 
 man -wK Kernighan |
 while IFS= read -r l; do 
      # filter authors section from the manual page
      authors=$(man -P cat "$l" 2>/dev/null | sed '/AUTHORS/,/^[^ ]/!d');
      # if the authors section mentions Kerningham print the page
      if grep "$what" <<<"$authors" >/dev/null; then 
           echo "$l"; 
      fi;
 done

 /usr/share/man/man1/chem.1.gz
 /usr/share/man/man1/gawk.1.gz
 ...
```

Comment: This is working, thanks